# How to automatically restore the previous window layout after gdb?

Tags: gdb

I am unable to find any gdb-kill-hook or similar.

After calling gdb with gdb-many-windows the frame gets a new window layout.

I am trying to store the previous layout in a register and to restore it after quitting gdb.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of [Andreas Röhler](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/3940/andreas-r%c3%b6hler) I was able to create the following functions. In the gdb buffer you can press 'q' to quit gdb as usual and restore the previous layout.

```
;; Select a register number which is unlikely to get used elsewere
(defconst egdbe-windows-config-register 313465989
  "Internal used")

(defvar egdbe-windows-config nil)

(defun set-egdbe-windows-config ()
  (interactive)
  (setq egdbe-windows-config (window-configuration-to-register egdbe-windows-config-register)))

(defun egdbe-restore-windows-config ()
  (interactive)
  (jump-to-register egdbe-windows-config-register))

(defun egdbe-start-gdb (&optional gdb-args)
  ""
  (interactive)
  (set-egdbe-windows-config)
  (call-interactively 'gdb))

(defun egdbe-quit ()
  "finish."
  (interactive)
  (gud-basic-call "quit")
  (egdbe-restore-windows-config))

(defun egdbe-gud-mode-hook ()
  ""
  (local-unset-key (kbd "q"))
  (local-set-key (kbd "q") 'egdbe-quit))

(add-hook 'gud-mode-hook 'egdbe-gud-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
;; Select a register number which is unlikely to get used elsewere
(defconst my-windows-config-register 313465989
  "Internal used")

(defvar my-windows-config nil)

(defun set-my-windows-config ()
  (interactive) 
  (setq my-windows-config (window-configuration-to-register my-windows-config-register)))

(defun jump-to-my-windows-config ()
  (interactive)
  (jump-to-register my-windows-config-register))
```

One command to register, the other to jump resp. restore window-configuration.